# How do I change the field title on the "Generate automatic URL alias" checkbox in pathautho?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms, path-aliases

How do I change the title of the checkbox "Generate automatic URL alias" on the pathauto fieldset on the node add page?

In my hook_form_node_form_alter I don't see this anywhere in the $form.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to utilize the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, it may be a bit easier to administer and manage this change via the admin rather than in code.